# Inherit ContentControl and add property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I'm trying to make a custom control that is basically a `ContentControl` with some special templating to open in a specific way.  In order to control this, I want to have a simple `IsFlyoutOpen` property that controls open/close. I tried to just inherit `ContentControl` and add a dependency property:

```
public class FlyoutContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public bool IsFlyoutOpen
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsFlyoutOpenProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsFlyoutOpenProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsFlyoutOpen.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFlyoutOpenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsFlyoutOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(FlyoutContentControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

This is fine, but when I create a content template targeted at this type, it won't let me template bind to it.  Here is my (condensed) template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CtFlyoutPanel" TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:FlyoutContentControl}">
  <Grid>
    <Border x:Name="RectHelpClip" Background="Transparent">
      <Border Background="{StaticResource BrHelpBackground}" RenderTransformOrigin="1,0">
        <Border.Style>
          <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{TemplateBinding IsFlyoutOpen}" Value="True">
                ...animations
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </Border.Style>
      </Border>
    </Border>
    ... other stuff
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

What am I missing?  Why can't I trigger on the new property?

Comment: `Binding="{Binding IsFlyoutOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`

Comment: Or `RelativeSource AncestorType=graphicElements:FlyoutContentControl`

Comment: That was the missing key, thanks!  If you make it an answer I will accept...